# TextField enabled in dev but disabled in production

Tags: reactjs

When I run React project with Fuse react template, the textfield works fine in development but does not accept input in production. What might the problem be?

Below is the textfield block:

```
<TextFieldFormsy
                   className="mb-16"
                   type="text"
                   name="username"
                   label="Username"
                   value={username}
                   onChange={(event) => setUserName(event.target.value)}
                   validations={{
                       minLength: 4
                   }}
                   validationErrors={{
                       minLength: 'Min character length is 4'
                   }}
                   InputProps={{
                       endAdornment:
                           <InputAdornment position="end">
                               <Icon className="text-20" color="action">email</Icon>
                           </InputAdornment>
                   }}
                   variant="outlined"
                   required
               />
```

Comment: provide more information like screenshots of development and production environment

Comment: Could you share your code in stackbiltz or codesandbox?